# Need help locating/clicking a drop down located in table using selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a script to locate/click a dropdown and the click any of the item from the selected drop down using selenium and python.

Below is the code and would like your help to make it better if its correct and correct it if its not correct way of doing it.

Code Snippet:

```
table1 = self.browser.find_element_by_id('user-list-table')
trows = table1.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for trow in trows:
    tcols = trow.find_element_by_tag_name('td')
    for tcol in tcols:
        if tcol ==("//button[@id='dropdownMenu1'][3]"):
            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(tcol).click()
            self.browser.find_element_by_link("//a[contains(text(),'Edit User')][3]").click()
```

HTML snippet :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable" id="user-list-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                        <th>Patient Load<br>Permanent | Temporary</th>
                        <th>No. of Tasks<br>Priority | Total</th>
                        <th>Tasks Per Day (completed)<br>Week | Month | Quarter</th>
                        <th class="text-right">User Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td class="text-center"><i class="status status-available">01</i></td>
                        <td>Tracy</td>
                        <td>Jones</td>
                        <td>1001</td>
                        <td>10 | 5</td>
                        <td>30 | 50</td>
                        <td>45 | 60 | 50</td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                User Actions
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                              </button>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="patient-assignment.html"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Assign Patients</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#User-Calendar-Today"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Todays Availability</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="user-profile.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> View Profile</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="user-account.html"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit User</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Deactivate User</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: My HTML file is too long and am not able to post it here. Is there any other way of sharing it.

Comment: jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n5evsaof/3/. Please let me know whether this helps

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n5evsaof/4/

Comment: what is the error?  can you just not seem to click the correct link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not certain I understand the problem you're experience (or trying to solve) well enough to help, I will try.

If I were you, attempting to click specific items from a list, I would just create a list of those items in the first place and then loop through it a single time, clicking as I went.  The code might look something like this.

```
item_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@id="dropdownMenu1"]') #you can add further specifications as necessary
```

At the very least, you can nix a couple `for loops` if you would just first create a list of the items you wanted to check.  [See docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html).

Does that help at all?  I see that you're already finding elements (rather than just a single element), so I likely don't understand the problem well enough to advise fully.  Consider providing greater clarification about your problem/objective in the comments or editing your questions.  Thanks and best of luck!

EDIT: Although it's implied in my answer, I should be clearer.  I believe that if you're simply trying to *reach* elements through loops and checks, it likely makes sense to use XPATH.  it is best suited to finding very specific (one-off) elements in an XML document.  Just my tuppence.

SECOND EDIT:

Here is a list of the links you need (I think):

```
list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@role="presentation"]/a') # len(list) == 99
```

Then, as said above, you can just loop this one list and `.click()` each link.

```
for link in list_of_links:
    link.click()
```

Let me know if it works.  Best of luck!!

Comment: In the above code, i have not taken into account the <<div class="dropdown"> while finding all the column[td] which has the drop down items present, however, the link given below explains that the <div> class should also be considered if the items in the drop down need to be located. This is what made me think whether my approach was correct https://teammentordevelopment.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/best-approach-to-find-nested-elements-with-webdriver-when-xpath-becomes-your-best-friend/    @Bee Smears

Comment: @KK16 Do you have a link or is it only an html doc?  my understanding is no you don't need to use the div, especially if all of the nested items share a class and one more distinguishing characteristic.  that should suffice using xpath.

Comment: i just got the HTML doc, i do not really have a link, below is the link to the HTML doc, hope this helps   http://jsfiddle.net/n5evsaof/4/ . jsfiddle.net, has HTML and the result(how the page and the drop down looks like, in the results window]

Comment: @KK16 that will likely suffice.  can you give me a couple examples of the elements you want returned?

Comment: @ Bee Smears, my goal is to click on any of the rows in the table, get control of the drop down in the last column[td] and click on any of the drop down items[links to other pages in the application]. though i somehow got half way through, reading through link posted above made me question about my approach  . Hope my question is clear.

Comment: @KK16 so the end goal is to `.click()` a link in the drop down menus, positioned to the far right of the page?  from what i can tell there are 20+ drop down menus.  you want to follow each of the links (5) inside of each of the drop downs (~24)?  (I don't necessarily need to know the tags you think are appropriate (though you're prolly right).  I need to know what on the page you want done...)

Comment: Clicking on "Today's availability" drop down item pops up a window with two drop downs and a "submit" button. The code to this is available in the same HTML file right below "<!-- Modals -->" tag in the end of the HTML and i dont think i have fully understood the concept of reading that pop up and doing some actions with the controls in the pop up. any pointers to that would help

Comment: I unfortunately don't get that behavior -- i.e., pop up window with drop down.  That's b/c all I have is an `.html` file.  But the bottom line is that you can select those items `...xpath('//a[@data-target="#User-Calendar-Today"]')`.  Does that make sense?  Xpath will definitely be a better option for you in this project.  Good luck and, if the answer solves your problem, please mark it as correct for future users.

Comment: yeah it does make sense. will proceed in the same direction. how do i mark it as correct? am new to stackoverflow and still getting to know it

Comment: I think there's a check mark by the answer that you can check if you think it's correct; but I don't know for sure bc I'm kind of new myself.  no worries if it's not there.  good luck with your project!

Comment: have marked it correct, you have been prompt enough to help out. thanks :)