# Identifying a dropdown menu within a table (Selenium in Python)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble identifying the pulldown menu on a webpage. The dropdown menu is within a table.  The `Inspect Element` is shown below:

```
<table cellspacing="9" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="This table is for page layout only">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="131" valign="top" bgcolor="#444444" align="left" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td valign="top" align="left">
                <map id="events" name="events"></map>
                <img height="468" width="544" border="0" alt="HALOE events for 10-OCT-1995 displayed on a cylindrical projection" usemap="#events" src="../coverage/index.php?boxaction=drawLatLonPlot&u=1490"></img>
                <br></br>
                <form name="chooseEvents" action="index.php" method="post">
                    <span class="subtitle" style="color:#ff3333"></span>
                    <select size="1" name="param">
                        <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                        <option value="1"></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                    </select>
```

The dropdown menu I'm interested in is:

```
<select size="1" name="param">
```

I've looked at other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747868/need-help-locating-clicking-a-drop-down-located-in-table-using-selenium) of doing this, but the `Inspect Element` text to identify the dropdown menu is not of a similar format.  This is the only dropdown menu on the webpage.  How can I find and select the value for this dropdown menu using Selenium in Python?

So far, I can open the webpage, but I'm having trouble selecting / manipulating that dropdown menu. My current code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

import unittest
import time

class SelectOptionTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://haloe.gats-inc.com/download/index.php?boxaction=dspProfiles&u=1490")

    def test_SelectOptionn(self):
        driver = self.driver
        dropdown = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.level1")
        print(dropdown)

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the dropdown using the `name` attribute and select options using [Select](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) class

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_name('param')
select = Select(dropdown)
select.select_by_value(value)
```